# How to update by reading and looping through all the rows?

Tags: mysql

The following is an example structure:

```
table `pligg`
#id   #alpha     #num
1       a        null
2       b        null
3       c        null
4       a        null
5       d        null
6       b        null
7       a        null
8       e        null
```

I'd like to update the databse like this after a single mysqli query:

```
table `pligg`
#id   #alpha     #num
1       a        1
2       b        1
3       c        1
4       a        2
5       d        1
6       b        2
7       a        3
8       e        1
```

What I'm trying to do is to update the column `num` with the number of duplicate.
I tried this query, but in vain

```
UPDATE pligg SET 'num' = COUNT(DISTINCT alpha) WHERE 'id'<id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
UPDATE pligg a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT a.id, a.alpha, COUNT(1) AS dup_cnt
    FROM pligg a
    INNER JOIN pligg b ON a.id >= b.id AND a.alpha = b.alpha
    GROUP BY a.id, a.alpha
) b ON a.id = b.id
SET a.num = b.dup_cnt
```

---

### [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b18b2/1/0)

Comment: Well, it works so nice on less rows. But i takes a lot of time when there is 48000 rows! Can the code be tweaked to make it run faster? :)